# Accessing request parameters from the response callback in Request module

Tags: node.js, request

How could we access the request parameters from the **response callback** when using [Request](https://github.com/request/request) module?

For example, the following "dog" (and so on) value could be passed via  looping a list:

```
var u   = require('util');
var url = "http://example.com/animals/%s";

request.get({uri: u.format(url, "dog")}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

       //how could we access the value 'dog' here?
       //something like this: console.log(uri.params.animal); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use closure property of js.

```
var u   = require('util');
var url = "http://example.com/animals/%s";

var param = "dog";
request.get({uri: u.format(url, param )}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       //how could we access the value 'dog' here?
       console.log(param);
    }
}
```